# Why won't Budgie 17.04 fully install?

Tags: budgie

I recently installed Ubuntu 16 on my HP Probook 4520s and love it. Yesterday I upgraded to 17.04 and it worked fine. But I wanted a little more menu capability, so I looked up how to install Budgie 17.04, made the boot able usb, and restarted. It booted from the usb, and on the login screen, it showed I now had the option of Ubuntu (default), Budgie desktop, and Unity 8. I signed into Budgie, and it had the menu, the toolbar and (after I installed the dock program from Ubuntu programs) the little floating dock. However, no desktop background (just black) and no welcome screen with setup options. No prompt to ask if you want to try or install now, no place to update drivers, nothing I am seeing on pics and videos online. After restarting a few times, my wife suggested I remove the usb. So I shut down, remove, and restart. It still shows Budgie as an option, so I go in. Same as before. So it seems it is only half installed?? Is this an issue because I've already got Ubuntu 17.04? Do I need to wipe Ubuntu first, and if so how? As I said, I'm relatively new to Linux, but I like it, so calling any geek to throw me a bone and figure this out. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(budgie-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(budgie-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall budgie-desktop
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```